# Unit integral condition on the output layer

Tags: objective-functions, probability-distribution

I want to train a neural network on some input data from a probability distribution (say a Gaussian). The loss function would normally be $-\sum\log(f(x_i))$, where the sum is over the whole data (or in this case a mini batch) and $f$ is the NN function. However I need to enforce the fact that $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=1$, in order for $f$ to be a real probability distribution. How can I add that to the loss function? Thank you!

Comment: The loss you mentioned is used for multi class classification. Is your problem classification or regression?

Comment: I am given data points generated from a function (distribution) as input, and I want to train a NN to approximate that function. I am not sure if it is classification or regression. I just want to train the network to approximate f.

Comment: But apparently the function is a probability distribution. The final output will be taken from a single node I guess?

Comment: Both the input and the output are one single node, yes. It can be shown mathematically that given data generated by a probability distribution, the function that generated the data is the one minimizing the loss function I wrote there. I just need to impose that normalization (otherwise the constant function equal to 1 would give the smallest loss). But I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: I assume the inputs are continuous?

Comment: The inputs are generated randomly from the distribution. They are not continuous, unless you generate infinitely many, which is not possible.

Comment: @AlexMarshall Your description of the function **$f$** is confusing. *...f  is the NN function....* and then, *...f  to be a real probability distribution...*. And, previously you desribe the loss: *The loss function would normally be −∑log(f(xi)),...*. I think you need to clear up the question and method a bit more.

Comment: @naive So I have an unknown probability distribution, let's say it's a gaussian distribution (this is also a function, as I can write it as f(x, mu, sigma)). I have some samples from the distribution and I want to build a NN such that given these sampled numbers as input, the NN learns to approximate the real (unknown) distribution. So if I pass a new number to the NN, it will give me something close to the value of the gaussian at that number.

Comment: @naive It can be shown mathematically that the loss function that I mentioned there is minimized only when the NN approximates the real function (intuitively, you want to find the function/distribution for which the numbers that you sampled are the most likely to appear). However, a probability distribution (such as a gaussian) must be normalized. My question is how do I impose the normalization condition to the NN such that it won't give me, for example numbers bigger than one, or numbers that would add up to more than one.

Comment: I think your first comment is clear. But, the second conflates the idea of a probability distribution function ( pdf) and probability.

Comment: From what I understood, your problem is of approximating a probability distribution function. This is not an easy task. You might find different probability distribution functions with similar losses for the training set that you provide. And, for the matter of normal distribution -- the normalizing constant can be used which is a function of the variance -- that I assume your function would have to approximate.

Comment: @naive oh sorry, you are right, I mean pdf. But yes, there could be many pdf that could produce the samples that I have with a high probability. But that's ok. I don't need the exact pdf, just something approximate. But that is mainly a second worry. the first one is how can I define a loss function itself that will force my NN the learn a good enough pdf? And in the case of the gaussian, yes, the NN should discover on its own that normalization constant. I am just not sure how to approach the problem.

Comment: For defining a loss function you need to have the actual output and predicted output. According to your description there does not seem to have an actual output. It seems this problem can be handled better through unsupervised learning techniques.

Comment: @naive But what is wrong with the loss I suggested? Shouldn't the network get pretty close to the tru pdf by using that loss?